# FileNotFoundError when trying to install PyICU

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, anaconda, pyicu

When I try to install PyICU I get the error message "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" (in German below in the code).

From other questions I have learned that I might have to do with my path. But since I am new to Python I really don't know what to do with this information.

```
(C:\Users\max.nkern\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3) C:\Users\max.nkern>pip install git+https://github.com/ovalhub/pyicu
Collecting git+https://github.com/ovalhub/pyicu
Cloning https://github.com/ovalhub/pyicu to c:\users\max~1.nke\appdata\local\temp\pip-9reie9cq-build
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MAX~1.NKE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-9reie9cq-build\setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    ICU_VERSION = check_output(('icu-config', '--version')).strip()
  File "c:\users\max.nkern\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "c:\users\max.nkern\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 693, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "c:\users\max.nkern\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\users\max.nkern\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1223, in _execute_child
    cwd, startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MAX~1.NKE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-9reie9cq-build\
```

At this point I really don't know how to continue.

Please give me a hand!

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same problem. Then I followed these installation instructions to the letter: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU/

Comment: Ty so much! After thoroughly following the instructions it worked!